# Ensure a certain line of code is evaluated early enough

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, redux

I need to set default timezone for all moment calls in app's lifetime, so the logical thing to do was put the setter in the entry point file, but it turns out it is not the first thing to get evaluated. One of my reducers has `moment().format()` as it's initial state, and it's evaluated before the entry point. Therefore, the resulting datetime string has incorrect offset.

Is there any way to ensure some code gets evaluated before other? The initial state issue can probably be solved by replacing an object with a function, but I still wonder how you would approach solving such issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be relying on the execution order of disparate sections of code.  Even if you get it to work in the moment (pun intended), you're creating a situation that is destined to cause bugs down the line due to an unrelated refactor or feature add elsewhere.

Instead, I would write a middleman function that returns moment to you, with the TZ set correctly.  Something like;

```
momentWithTz () {
    return moment().tz("America/Los_Angeles");
}
```

And then simply use this instead of the traditional `moment` in the rest of your code, ensuring that the TZ is set explicitly instead of trusting that it was set previously by something else completely unrelated.